# Enviar notificaciones a una aplicación Android desde fuera

Tags: java, android, webservice

Estimados , recurro a ustedes para saber que me recomiendan a la hora de enviar notificaciones , ah que me refiero con esto , los pongo un poco en contexto ,

Actualmente estoy en medio de un desarrollo en donde , tengo 2 aplicaciones echas con android studio , uno representara una billetera , y la otra aplicación  representara a un CAJERO AUTOMATICO (ATM) , lo que quiero es que cuando desde la aplicación del cajero , yo escriba el NUMERO de IDENTIFICADOR  (Celular talvez) 
y ponga la plata que quiero depositar , cuando le de OK , en mi aplicacion instalada en el teléfono , me salga una notificación de que se realizo el deposito ,Nose si me doy a entender ,

dejo unas imágenes que hablan mas que mi explicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si te refieres a Push Notifications, ya tienes implementada esta parte con FCM? Revisa [ask].

Comment: aun no tengo nada implementado Jorge , justamente mi pregunta era que me recomendaban para realizar esta tarea

Comment: Para trabajar push notifications puedes utilizar Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Para que tu pregunta tenga  mejor aceptación revisa [ask].